# illustrator 3D offset

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I want to create a 2 pt offset of that red object around the shield (and want to cut it from the shield). I have applied 3d- rotate. expanded.

but it is not happening. the offset is getting weird shape not exactly like the red one is appearing.
I can see a slanted outline in outline mode, offset is following that slanted shape.

how can I make a 2pt offset of that red object (exactly like the one am seeing)? thankyou.[image]

Comment: You can't simply copy the red object and move it? I *really* wouldn't be using AI's 3D effect here.

Comment: you mean rotate the bounding box of that red shape?? not applying the 3D-rotate?? manually?

Comment: Well it's *difficult* to know what you *want*. I have *no clue* what you are envisioning. The only thing I can say with some certainty is you *don't* need any "3D" here. But yes, duplicate the red shape and then transform it into the position you want.

Comment: okay. thank you.